# Blank slide getting added when using allowframebreaks in beamer

Tags: beamer, longtable, allowframebreaks

I am using long tables in my beamer slide and therefore trying to distribute them over multiple slides using allowframebreaks command in the frame. The long table is coming correctly however, a blank slide is getting added in the output at the end of the frame. How do I avoid this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}%
\usepackage{etoolbox, xparse} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{longtable}


% set colors
\definecolor{myNewColorA}{RGB}{158, 27,50}
\definecolor{myNewColorB}{RGB}{158, 27,50}
\definecolor{myNewColorC}{RGB}{158, 27,50} % {130,138,143}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=myNewColorC}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=myNewColorB, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myNewColorA, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=myNewColorA, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{caption name}{fg=myNewColorA}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%------------------------------------------------------------
%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=0.75cm]{iitb1.png}} 

% logo of my university


\titlegraphic{%
\includegraphics[width=3.0cm]{iitb1.png}
}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\footnotesize}
\title[CL689]{Heat Integration Analysis for an Industrial
Ethylbenzene Plant using Pinch Analysis}%title
%\subtitle{ }%%subtitle
%\author[Priyam Nayak]{Priyam Nayak - 214026014\inst{1}}%%authors
\author[Priyam Nayak]{Priyam Nayak - 214026014}
%\institute[IITB]{Indian Institute of Technology Bombay\inst{1}}
\institute[IITB]{Indian Institute of Technology Bombay}
\date[\textcolor{white}{Project Presentation}]
{CL689 - Energy Integration in Chemical Processes\\ Project Presentation\\ Nov 22, 2022}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:
%\AtBeginSection[]
%{
%  \begin{frame}
%    \frametitle{Contents}
%    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
%  \end{frame}
%}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
% ------Contents below------
%------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


% consider removing it if it's too redundant
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

%------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Problem Data - Cold Stream}
\begin{table}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Stream} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{in} ($\degree$C)} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{out} ($\degree$C)} & \textbf{Heat Duty (kW)} & \textbf{Heat Capacity (kW/$\degree$C)} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
C1 & 162 & 206 & 9020 & 205 \\ \hline
C2 & 158 & 200 & 3210 & 76 \\ \hline
C3 & 205 & 206 & 4445 & 4445 \\ \hline
C4 & 40 & 180 & 75 & 0.5 \\ \hline
C5 & 34 & 87 & 1007 & 19 \\ \hline
C6 & 241 & 242 & 8999 & 8999 \\ \hline
C7 & 221 & 244 & 5951 & 259 \\ \hline
C8 & 271 & 279 & 2105 & 263 \\ \hline
C9 & 55 & 130 & 230 & 3 \\ \hline
C10 & 33 & 90 & 2625 & 46 \\ \hline
C11 & 242 & 246 & 16989 & 4247 \\ \hline
C12 & 221 & 236 & 8082 & 539 \\ \hline
C13 & 268 & 282 & 3789 & 271 \\ \hline
C14 & 55 & 130 & 512 & 7 \\ \hline
C15 & 38 & 48 & 537 & 54 \\ \hline
C16 & 104 & 105 & 447 & 447 \\ \hline
C17 & 103 & 104 & 407 & 407 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
%\caption{Cold stream data}
%\label{tab:cs-data}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\section*{Acknowledgement}  
\begin{frame}

\textcolor{myNewColorA}{\huge{\centerline{Thank you!}}}
\vspace*{0.5cm}

\textcolor{myNewColorA}{\Large{\centerline{E-mail: }}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: pdf output from overleaf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- if you want to use the `\degree` macro, you must either define it or load one of the packages which provide it. Overleaf is very good at hiding error messages, but there should be a red square at the top right which alerts you of error. If latex encounters an error, it only syntax checks the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output
- your table is also too wide to fit on the frame. You can safe a bit of room by making the last column smaller
- even though beamer does not have a floating mechanism, environments like `table` etc aren't meant to span more than one slide. As you commented out the caption, it is also not really useful for anything. Remove it.
- you don't need to load `color`, `hyperref` or `etoolbox`, beamer loads them for you
- with up-to-date latex, you also don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, that's the default
- don't load the same package more than once
- unrelated to latex, but are you sure that you really need such a long table in your presentation? The audience will hardly remember all the numbers. Usually it is better to present what you learnt from the table instead of showing the table. If you really must include the table, have a look at the documentation of the `booktabs` package on how to create professional looking tables.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}%
\usepackage{
%etoolbox, 
xparse} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{gensymb}


% set colors
\definecolor{myNewColorA}{RGB}{158, 27,50}
\definecolor{myNewColorB}{RGB}{158, 27,50}
\definecolor{myNewColorC}{RGB}{158, 27,50} % {130,138,143}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=myNewColorC}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=myNewColorB, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myNewColorA, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=myNewColorA, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{caption name}{fg=myNewColorA}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%------------------------------------------------------------
%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=0.75cm]{iitb1.png}} 

% logo of my university


\titlegraphic{%
\includegraphics[width=3.0cm]{example-image-duck}
}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\footnotesize}
\title[CL689]{Heat Integration Analysis for an Industrial
Ethylbenzene Plant using Pinch Analysis}%title
%\subtitle{ }%%subtitle
%\author[Priyam Nayak]{Priyam Nayak - 214026014\inst{1}}%%authors
\author[Priyam Nayak]{Priyam Nayak - 214026014}
%\institute[IITB]{Indian Institute of Technology Bombay\inst{1}}
\institute[IITB]{Indian Institute of Technology Bombay}
\date[\textcolor{white}{Project Presentation}]
{CL689 - Energy Integration in Chemical Processes\\ Project Presentation\\ Nov 22, 2022}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:
%\AtBeginSection[]
%{
%  \begin{frame}
%    \frametitle{Contents}
%    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
%  \end{frame}
%}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
% ------Contents below------
%------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


% consider removing it if it's too redundant
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

%------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Problem Data - Cold Stream}
%\begin{table}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|c|c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Stream} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{in} ($\degree$C)} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{out} ($\degree$C)} & \textbf{Heat Duty (kW)} & \textbf{Heat Capacity (kW/$\degree$C)} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%%
\endhead
C1 & 162 & 206 & 9020 & 205 \\ \hline
C2 & 158 & 200 & 3210 & 76 \\ \hline
C3 & 205 & 206 & 4445 & 4445 \\ \hline
C4 & 40 & 180 & 75 & 0.5 \\ \hline
C5 & 34 & 87 & 1007 & 19 \\ \hline
C6 & 241 & 242 & 8999 & 8999 \\ \hline
C7 & 221 & 244 & 5951 & 259 \\ \hline
C8 & 271 & 279 & 2105 & 263 \\ \hline
C9 & 55 & 130 & 230 & 3 \\ \hline
C10 & 33 & 90 & 2625 & 46 \\ \hline
C11 & 242 & 246 & 16989 & 4247 \\ \hline
C12 & 221 & 236 & 8082 & 539 \\ \hline
C13 & 268 & 282 & 3789 & 271 \\ \hline
C14 & 55 & 130 & 512 & 7 \\ \hline
C15 & 38 & 48 & 537 & 54 \\ \hline
C16 & 104 & 105 & 447 & 447 \\ \hline
C17 & 103 & 104 & 407 & 407 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
%\caption{Cold stream data}
%\label{tab:cs-data}
%\end{table}
\end{frame}

\section*{Acknowledgement}  
\begin{frame}

\textcolor{myNewColorA}{\huge{\centerline{Thank you!}}}
\vspace*{0.5cm}

\textcolor{myNewColorA}{\Large{\centerline{E-mail: }}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. I will find out how to implement them and try implementing them. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Priyam You're welcome! It is very refreshing to see questions which actually provide a MWE without having to spend half a day asking for one! I hope you keep asking questions :)